# Meteor iron router doesn't find in-subdirectory templates

Tags: templates, meteor, iron-router

Meteor iron router, works if my template is saved in the same directory.
If I move my template to a subdirectory, then it doesn't find the template.

Why is that ?

How to make iron find templates in sub-directories ?

ex:
This doesn't work:

[image]

but this work :

[image]

The difference is that I put back "home.html" and "home.js" under the "client" directory.

Comment: Suspect something is off with the loading order. Can you rename your ```routes.js``` as ```0_routes.js``` and then see if the first approach works?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your configuration. Iron router doesn't have a problem finding any templates in project directory.